# xercesImpl-2.11.0 corrupted the excel file generated by jxls-2.4.3

Tags: java, xerces, jxls

i found a wired problem, I use jxls-2.4.3 to generate the excel file and i have xercesImpl-2.11.0 to parse the xml but the problem is if i have xercesImpl-2.11.0 in my lib then the report generated by jxls is corrupted.
How to solve this problem and is there any dependency between these two jars

Comment: Do you have any error, or can you describe how the excel file looks like when corrupted (is it an empty file, is it a valid zip archive, is it a valid excel file with invalid content, etc.)?

Comment: When i am trying to open the generated excel the error occure:- Excel cannot open the file xyz.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of file.